# Controlling current media player in Windows without sending media key keystrokes?

Tags: c#, media-player

I have a keyboard with media keys on it, the usual stuff, play/pause, stop, previous, next, as well as volume control.

I would like to mimick this type of behavior, only from my own program. Meaning that if Spotify is running, playing a song, and my program says "Pause" I would like Spotify to pause. All this without me hardcoding support for Spotify.

I know that I can use something like "SendKeys" to fake the user pushing the corresponding key on the keyboard, I've seen AutoHotKeys scripts for this.

But what is the API functions that I would use directly from my program? Do they even exist?

Answer (score 1):

An easy option would be to use the [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm) dll. I've found amazing-andrew's repo [AutoHotkey.Interop](https://github.com/amazing-andrew/AutoHotkey.Interop) very useful for this.

Then you can execute ControlSend like so:

```
//grab a copy of the AutoHotkey singleton instance
var ahk = AutoHotkeyEngine.Instance;

//execute any raw ahk code
ahk.ExecRaw("ControlSend, , {Media_Play_Pause}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow"); // send directly to the window
```